# NSPopover subclass: how to know that the popover closes?

Tags: nspopover

I'm writing an `NSPopover` subclass, and I want the popover to execute some code when it closes.

However, the `-close` method isn't generally called when the popover closes (when the user clicks outside the popover), neither is the `-peformClose:` method.

I tried setting the popover as the `delegate` of its window, but none of the `NSWindowDelegate` method (`-windowDidClose:`, `-windowDidMinimize:`, `-windowDidResignKey:`, etc.) is called when the popover closes.

I know that `-popoverDidClose:` is sent to the popover `delegate` when it has closed (and this appears reliable), but that is a delegate method, not a method of `NSPopover`. And the popover should not be the delegate of itself to determine when it has closed.

Any suggestion?